# jquery+dataTables column autowidth

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I have a problem with column width settings. 
It  works correct without per-column search, but don't works with searching

```
$('#headerListTable tfoot th').each(
 function() {
  var title = $('#headerListTable thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
  $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" style=""/>');
});
```

[image: Not-working auto-width]

Helps only manual width setting in dataTables

```
   ...
"aoColumns": [
            { "sWidth": "20%" },
            { "sWidth": "30%" }, 
            { "sWidth": "20%" },
            { "sWidth": "5%" },
            { "sWidth": "15%" },
            { "sWidth": "15%" }
        ]
...
```

[image]

Question: Is it possible set column width automatically?

[JSFiddle Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zond/v1582e9b/)

Comment: `"bAutoWidth": true` is a option in DT which gives auto-width to columns based on column text . seems fiddle working good can hlep me reproduce the issue . cheers

Comment: @supercool it doesn't work ((